# How do I relate the code from seperate classes in order for methods and actions events to work with one another

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, enums

First of all this is basically not a repost because I am asking different questions in this than my previous post and the only reason I am not deleting that post is because I am waiting for one of the users who has answered to respond to a question because he has helped a lot and knows what the situation is

TLDR; not a repost

I've come to the conclusion that I have 3 questions.

1: How do I use the variables and arrayList of the company class in the Employee class.

2: How should I make the actionListeners so the operate correctly.

3: Would the methods in the Company class work correctly? If not, how should I make them?

Check the link given in the paragraph above for the prompt to my question. Here is a link to the prompt my professor has provided https://www.dropbox.com/s/omeg19u6ns2pot2/Work%205.doc so you guys can see what I am trying to reach. I would usually get help from the tutors but they aren't available at this time in particular. Help is really, really highly appreciated. I have to finish this by tonight. I know this is a bit too much for this website but it is the only way you can get a good grasp on what is happening. I have already started a post on this problem and moved a bit further but no one is replyting to my questions on that post anymore so I am doing another one.

Here is the driver called GUI.java

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

private JPanel employeePanel;

private JPanel buttonPanel2;
private JPanel positionPanel;

private JPanel namePanel2;
private JPanel buttonPanel1;
private JPanel upperLine;
private JPanel lowerLine;
private JPanel companyAndPresidentPanel;
private JPanel companyPanel;
private JRadioButton designButton;
private JRadioButton salesButton;
private JRadioButton manuButton;
private JTextField firstField;
private JTextField lastField;
private JLabel firstLabel;
private JLabel lastLabel;
private JLabel cNameLabel;
private JLabel presidentLabel;
private JLabel logo;
private ButtonGroup bGroup;


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//adding default serial ID so class is "used"

/*
 * Position p;
    p=p.SALES;
    */

Company c;
Employee e;
private JButton addButton;
private JButton clearButton;
private JButton printButton;
private JButton newButton;
private JButton exitButton;

String companyName;

public GUI(){


    companyName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the name of this company", companyName);
    setTitle("Company Employees");
    setSize(425,450);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main();
    subPanels();
    add(companyAndPresidentPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(employeePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);   


    //pack();

}
public void subPanels(){

    positionPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel1 = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
    employeePanel = new JPanel();
    namePanel2= new JPanel();
    upperLine = new JPanel();
    lowerLine = new JPanel();
    employeePanel.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    designButton = new JRadioButton("Design");
    salesButton = new JRadioButton("Sales");
    manuButton = new JRadioButton("Manufacturing");

     addButton = new JButton("Add Employee");
     clearButton = new JButton("Clear Button");
     printButton = new JButton("Print Company Employees");
     newButton = new JButton("New Company");
     exitButton = new JButton("Exit");



    firstField = new JTextField(10);
    lastField = new JTextField(10);

    firstLabel = new JLabel("First Name:");
    lastLabel = new JLabel("Last Name:");


    bGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    bGroup.add(designButton);
    bGroup.add(salesButton);
    bGroup.add(manuButton);


    positionPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    positionPanel.add(designButton);
    positionPanel.add(salesButton);
    positionPanel.add(manuButton);
    positionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Position"));


    upperLine.add(printButton);
    lowerLine.add(newButton);
    lowerLine.add(exitButton);
    buttonPanel1.add(upperLine, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buttonPanel1.add(lowerLine, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    buttonPanel2.add(addButton);
    buttonPanel2.add(clearButton);



    namePanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    namePanel2.add(firstLabel);
    namePanel2.add(firstField);
    namePanel2.add(lastLabel);
    namePanel2.add(lastField);


    employeePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add Employee"));
    employeePanel.add(namePanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    employeePanel.add(positionPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    employeePanel.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    employeePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add Employee"));


    printButton.addActionListener(new aListener());
    addButton.addActionListener(new aListener());
    clearButton.addActionListener(new aListener());
    newButton.addActionListener(new aListener());
    exitButton.addActionListener(new aListener());

}
/*
 * if data manager.add employee.equals("too many design")
 * joption pane too many
 */
public void main(){



    companyAndPresidentPanel = new JPanel();
    companyPanel = new JPanel();
    presidentLabel = new JLabel("President:Amin Oskoui");
    cNameLabel = new JLabel("");
    logo = new JLabel("");
    cNameLabel.setText(companyName);

    ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("src/company.png");
    logo.setIcon(myImage);

    companyPanel.add(logo);
    companyPanel.add(cNameLabel);

    companyAndPresidentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    companyAndPresidentPanel.add(companyPanel);
    companyAndPresidentPanel.add(presidentLabel);





}
private class aListener implements ActionListener {
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String position;
    Position position2;
    int nEmployees, nCompanies, nDesign, nSales, nManu;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(e.getSource()==addButton){
            fName = firstField.getText();
            lName = lastField.getText();
            if(e.getSource() instanceof JRadioButton){
                if(manuButton.isSelected()){
                    position=(manuButton.getText());
                    position2.valueOf(position);
                }   
                else if(designButton.isSelected()){
                    position=(designButton.getText());
                    position2.valueOf(position);
                }
                else if(salesButton.isSelected()){
                    position=(salesButton.getText());
                    position2.valueOf(position);
                }
                c=new Company(nEmployees, nCompanies, nDesign, nSales, nManu);
                c.addEmployee(fName, lName, position2);
                c.printCompany();

            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==clearButton){
            firstField.setText("");
            lastField.setText("");
            bGroup.clearSelection();

        }
        else if (e.getSource()==printButton){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The employee list");//I don't have this working for it to show the list so I dunno what to do here.
        }
        else if (e.getSource()== newButton){

        }
        else if (e.getSource()==exitButton){
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args)//main class
{
      new GUI();
}

}
```

Here is the Data Manager called Company.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
public class Company {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//ensuring that the class corresponds with a serialized object

Position p;
Employee a;

private String companyName;//name of company
private String employeeName;
private String position;

final int maxCompanies = 2, maxEmployees = 7, maxSales = 1, maxDesign = 2, maxManufacturing = 4;

private static int numberOfCompanies;//the number of companies
private int numEmployees;//the number of employees
public int numDesign;//the number of employees in design
private int numManufacturing;// the number of employees in manufacturing
private int numSales;//the number of employees in sales

private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList;

public Company(Position position){
    this.p = position;

}
public Company(String cn){
    numEmployees = 0;
    numSales = 0;
    numDesign = 0;
    numManufacturing = 0;
    employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
public Company(int ec, int nc, int nd, int ns,int nm) {
    numEmployees = ec;
    numberOfCompanies = nc;
    numDesign = nd;
    numSales = ns;
    numManufacturing = nm;
}
public String addEmployee(String fName, String lName, Position p) {
       String errorMessage;
       errorMessage = "It is one of the errors";
    switch (p) {
        case SALES:
            //if there's less than 1 salesman, add them to the list
            if (numSales < 1) {
                Employee employee = new Employee(fName, lName, p);
                employeeList.add(employee);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is already a Sales representative.");

                }


        case DESIGN:
            if (numDesign < 2) {
                Employee employee2 = new Employee(fName, lName, p);
                employeeList.add(employee2);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are already two design employees.");            
                }


        case MANUFACTURING:
            if (numManufacturing < 4){
                Employee employee2 = new Employee(fName, lName, p);
                employeeList.add(employee2);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are already four manufacturers.");              
                }
        default:


    }
    return errorMessage;
    }
public static int getNumCompanies(){//return the number of companies 
    return numberOfCompanies;
}
public int getNumEmployees(){//get the number of employees
    return numEmployees;
}
public String printCompany(){//print the company with all of the positions
    String companyPrint;

    return companyName;
}
@Override
public String toString() {//converts everything to a string
    return "Company [position="  + ", companyName=" + companyName
            + ", employees=" + employeeList + ", numEmployees=" + numEmployees
            + ", numDesign=" + numDesign + ", numManufacturing="
            + numManufacturing + ", numSales=" + numSales + "]";
}

}
```

Here is the Data Element called Employee.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Employee {
private String fName;
private String lName;
private Position p2;

public Employee(String fName, String lName, Position p2) {
this.fName = fName;
this.lName = lName;
this.p2 = p2;

}
public String getFName(){
    return fName;
}
public String getLName(){
    return lName;
}
public Position getP2(){
    return p2;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Employee [fName=" + fName + ", lName =" + lName + ", p2 =" + p2 + "]";
}





}
```

Here is the enum class

```
//in Position.java
public enum Position {
DESIGN("Design"),
MANUFACTURING("Manufacturing"),
SALES("Sales");

private final String positionName;


private Position(String positionName) {
    this.positionName= positionName;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return positionName;
}
}
```

Comment: The only problem I see is that you are asking broad questions about a partially implemented assignment. Since you re-posted I am sure you have questions to be answered but you should focus on a single problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask one question per post, and I'm going to focus on your Employee class:

- As mentioned before, the constructor is broken.
- You need to use the parameters passed into the constructor and set the class fields.  For example:

---

```
public class Foo {
  private int bar;
  private String baz;

  public Foo(int bar, String baz) {
    this.bar = bar; // set class fields with parameters
    this.baz = baz;
  }

  // getter field so other classes can get necessary info
  public int getBar() {
    return bar;
  }

  public String getBaz() {
    return baz;
  }
}
```

- Your Employee constructor creates another instance of itself inside of it -- you have, `Employee employee = new Employee (fName, lName, p2);` inside of the constructor which shouldn't be there (not sure what purpose you think it serves) and will cause recursion infinitely til you run out of stack memory.
- Employee shouldn't even compile since you have a method inside of the constructor.
- Employee should not have an addEmployee method. This type of method would only be useful for a class that holds a collection of Employees -- and that's another class of yours. What purpose does it serve in Employee class? None.
- **Again** the class needs getter variables.
- I would remove the JOptionPane and any user interaction from the Employee class. This class is for holding together data that describes a single employee, not for interacting with the user. That function will be performed by other classes.
- If this were my code, I'd give Employee a main method simply for the purpose of testing the class. Alternatively you could create a small class that you delete later, say TestEmployee that has the main method and does this for you.
- The key to solving this and any coding problem is to divide and conquer, to solve each small problem one at a time and in isolation, but you've been told this before too.

I suggest that you ask other questions for each of your other classes and focus on your problems and classes **one class at a time**. Your question should not have tldr code or text in it.

---

**Edit 1**
For the benefit of others, here's links to your other questions. I suggest anyone answering this question to read the question and the comments to see what has been discussed previously:

- Deleted question: [Having problems getting variables and methods from multiple classes to work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043860)
- [Java trouble with ArrayLists when there are multiple classes and help fixing up the code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23038024/522444)

---

**Edit 2**
For the further benefit of others, here's the beginning of his assignment requirements:

CS103 36674 COMPUTER SCIENCE I      PROJECT 5       SPRING 2014        JUSTH

Date Due: 11:59pm, Sunday, April 13, 2014

Concepts tested by this program:

```
Static variable and methods
Multiple classes (Data Element/Data Structure/Data Manager/GUI driver)
Class relationships – Dependency and Aggregation
```

Images on a Label

```
Enumerated types
Layout Managers
Borders (bordered radio group)
Arraylists
```

You have decided to set up two companies to make and market two different items.  You will be the president of each company.  Each company will employ two people to design your product, four people to manufacture them, and one person to sell them.  Your task is to write a GUI-driven program to enter the names of the people you hire and their positions in your company.  You will enter the names of the employees for the first company and then the names of the employees for your second company. You will display a logo to represent your company with your name as President. You will not have more than 2 companies at this time.

Operation

- The user is first asked for the first company name.  A Logo will be displayed with the company name and will include your name as President.
- The user will enter the first and last name of the person hired and then indicate which position the person will fill.  The user then selects the Add Employee button.
- If the position selected is already filled (1 sales, or 2 design, or 4 manufacturing), an error message is displayed.
- When the user selects the Clear button, the first name and last name fields will be cleared.
- When the user selects the Print Employees button, the names of the employees will be displayed with their position.
- When the user selects the New Company button, the name of the second company is asked for and displayed with the logo, company name and your name as president.  If there are already two companies recorded, an error message is displayed.
- When the user closes the frame or presses the Exit button, the application exits.

Specifications

- Enumerated Class - Position
- Create an enumerated type called Position.  The valid values will be SALES, DESIGN, MANUFACTURING.  Add any additional  methods or instance variables as required by your design.
- Data Element – Employee class
- Create an Employee class.  It will contain instance variables of type String for the first name and last name.  It will contain an instance variable of type Position for the position.  Provide a constructor and a toString method.  Add any additional methods as required.
- Data Manager – Company class
- Create a Company class.  It will contain an ArrayList of Employee Objects.  It will have a static variable that keeps track of the number of companies that have been created and a static method that returns the value of this variable.  Provide a constructor and a method to addEmployee, a method to printCompany, and a toString method.  The addEmployee method will check that there is only 1 salesperson, 2 designers, and 4 manufacturing persons at a time and will check that there are no more than 7 employees of the company.  The addEmployee method will return a String indicating what the error is (i.e. “There is already a sales person in this company”) or a null if the employee was added.  If attempting to name a third company, an error message will be shown.  Make sure your class names and method names and parameters match the Javadoc that I provided for this class, or the JUnit test will not run correctly.

GUI driver – frame and panel classes

- Create a driver class with an ActionListener class.  Use Layout Managers and borders to make your panel look more professional.  Display the logo image at top of the panel.  Your panel will have an instance variable of type Company.  Use the addEmployee and printCompany methods of the Company class.  Use a dialog box to alert the user when there is an error.  If the New Company button is selected, ask the user for the company name, create a new variable of type Company, and display the new company name and logo.
- You will be using an image file (.jpg, .png, etc).  Place the image file in your src folder in your eclipse workspace.  If you are using a package, put your image file in the package folder under the src folder for your workspace.

When you create your ImageIcon:

- ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("src/xxxx.jpg") if you are using the default package under src
  ( ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon("src/xxpackageNamexx/xxx.jpg"); if you are using a package within your src folder.
  ( Zip your entire src folder and your doc folder with anything else that is required for this assignment.

---

**Edit 3**

- Note that per your instructions, Company class should not be a GUI class. Thus do not have it extend JPanel, but rather have it hold the list of Employees.

---

**Edit 4**
You state in comment:

> I have edited the code and done what you have told me. So I can fix up the methods but myself so they operate correctly but my question is how do I make the other action buttons that are left so they do there operation correctly and add to the arrayList so I can display the arrayList when the user clicks the print company button.

First things first. You should fix Employee and you should **test it** to be sure that it works. I'd also give Employee a `toString()` method that makes it easy to test.

Using my example from above:

```
public class Foo {
   private int bar;
   private String baz;

   public Foo(int bar, String baz) {
      this.bar = bar; // set class fields with parameters
      this.baz = baz;
   }

   // getter field so other classes can get necessary info
   public int getBar() {
      return bar;
   }

   public String getBaz() {
      return baz;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Foo [bar=" + bar + ", baz=" + baz + "]";
   }

   // main method solely for testing this Foo class
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Foo foo = new Foo(3, "baz test");
      System.out.println(foo);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I removed what you have told me and edited my code. On my previous post one of the users told me to create and addEmployee method similar to the one I created. So now that I have removed it how can I add to the employees and the employee types.

Comment: @user3482560: yes, they told you to create an `addEmployee(...)` method, but they didn't tell you to add it to your Employee class. I've gone through all your previous posts their answers and all, so trust me on this. Employee should not have this method; it belongs elsewhere. You should be able figure out which class needs this method, which class has a collection of Employees, right?

Comment: @user3482560: chit, your instructions tell you **exactly** which class should have the `addEmployee` method! Note that Company is still a *logical* class and not a view class. You should not have Company extend JPanel.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for the answers and edits. I have edited the code and done what you have told me. So I can fix up the methods but myself so they operate correctly but my question is how do I make the other action buttons that are left so they do there operation correctly and add to the arrayList so I can display the arrayList when the user clicks the print company button.

Comment: @user3482560: your *instructions* are even telling you to give the Employee class a `toString()` method. Am I good or what?

Comment: Thanks so, so much for your help I once again edited the Employee  class and tested it with a main and it worked. So now how should I make the action listeners so that they would operate as prompted when they press the buttons. When they press the new button it should repeat the process again. I tried copying the code from the GUI constructor and putting it in the getSource for new button but that just puts adds an the inputdialogbox and doesn't change anything on the GUI. Would I have to recopy all of the code in there?

Comment: And by the way your not just good but great for helping and instructing so much.

Comment: @user3482560: Your code is better, but get rid of Employee's static variables on the bottom of the class. They have no business being there and will only confuse.

Comment: Ok I changed it now. So what should I do with the action listeners now?

Comment: One thing at a time. I think that this question is done, we've fixed one problem, your Employee class. You should now work on the Company class, getting it to comply with the instructions since at present it does not. Again, do one thing at a time, test as you go. You're not ready to get the GUI working yet, and first need to get your other non-GUI classes working. If you get stuck with your Company problems, then ask another new question on this site. bye.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. Could you please still help when I encounter a problem because I don't have much time left so I can't keep making new posts on this site. You respond really quickly and have good advice and it would be much more efficient if you could just keep helping me on this thread. I also would like to apologize for taking so much of your time.

Comment: @user3482560: the best way to get quick useful answers is to ask succinct smart questions. That's one other reason why I advise you not to ask mega-questions but rather focused questions that deal with issues in one class. You will get help if your questions are well presented.

Comment: Yes I completely agree, but now that you have read through my prompt and my code you know exactly what I have to do and it would be easier for everyone. I do apologize for being so repetative and tedious with my questions except I really need to finish in the next 2-3 hours.

Comment: I promise only to ask specific questions as of now so I actually learn rather than copy code.